# Is it possible to position elements by their center?

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning

With `position: absolute`, you place an element by defining one of it's corners (often using the top and left properties). Is it possible to place it by defining it's center? (without knowing it's width/height?).

Comment: Why don't you use margin:0 auto; to center the element ?

Comment: Because I  don't want to center it, I want to posiition it.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question with this [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/K8S3L/)

Link to the similar question with my answer: [Position the center of an image using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022407/position-the-center-of-an-image-using-css/14318009#14318009)

You can then use top/left coordinates using pixels, and it will use the center of your object no matter which width/height and this may be dynamic fit to content. One problem may be you need to set some z-indexes and styles so the other wrapper divs won't bother the rest of your content, this may be a drawback to use this approach.

The solution lies in the fact to use a wrapper div, with the real positions, and within that another wrapper div containing styles: `position: relative;padding-top: 25%;margin-top: -100%;margin-left: -100%;`. The margin-left style will apply easily, but the margin-top needs the padding, hence the extra wrapper div.

If you want another approach, you will have to use Javascript I suppose.